# Correctly sending Flink state to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpointing

I'm building a Kafka -> Flink -> Kafka pipeline that works with delineated "session" data. My input Kafka topic has data in the following format and constitutes one session for `session_key`:

```
start_event(session_key, some_other_data...)
entry_event(session_key, some_other_data...)
entry_event(session_key, some_other_data...)
...
entry_event(session_key, some_other_data...)
end_event(session_key, some_other_data...)
```

Each session like this is about 100 events long, comes in quickly (every 1-2 seconds), all events share the same `session_key`, and I'm transforming the session into a series of 20 or so events that go into the output topic. To build these events, I need to know about the entire session, so I need to wait for the `end_event` to arrive to be able to run the processing and push output events to the output topic.

The implementation is fairly simple - key by `session_key`, store `start_event` into `ValueState`, entries into `ListState`, and then when `end_event` arrives, run the processing logic over all events and push the results into the output Kafka topic.

My question is around checkpointing and possible failures - let's say checkpointing starts after `end_event` makes it out of Kafka. The offset is committed to Kafka and the checkpointing barrier gets to my processing operator which fails right before it (Kafka is down now).

How should I correctly recover from this? If the Kafka offset is already committed, and no `end_event` will ever make it out of Kafka for that `session_key`, how do I trigger the processing operator for my saved state later on? Or would the Kafka offset not be committed in this scenario and `end_event` will go thru Flink once more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink commits Kafka offsets only for the sake of monitoring, but does not rely on them for fault tolerance (btw, it does it when checkpoints are completed):

> Note that Kafka source does NOT rely on committed offsets for fault tolerance. Committing offset is only for exposing the progress of consumer and consuming group for monitoring.

See [Consumer Offset Committing](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#consumer-offset-committing).

Topic offsets are saved as a part of the Kafka source state during a checkpoint. In the described scenario, the whole checkpoint would fail and Flink would start consuming topics starting from the offsets saved in the previous checkpoint. No messages would be lost, but some could be possibly duplicated (assuming AT_LEAST_ONCE checkpointing mode).

So yes, the end_event will go thru Flink once more.

Answer (score 1):

I think kafka offset not be committed in this scenario, offset is submitted in the notify phase of the checkpoint

The notify phase will only be triggered if the checkpoint of all operators is successful.